# Proving linearity of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The derivative for a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ defined in some open set containing $x$ at $x$ is defined (at least in Rudin and other references), if it exists, to be the **linear function** $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0} \left| \frac{f(x + v t) - f(x)}{t} - Av\right| = 0.
\end{equation}

Suppose we drop the bolded assumption that $A$ is linear; can we then prove, from the remaining definition, that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$ its derivative must be linear?

I suspect the answer is no (although I certainly understand why the derivative only makes intuitive sense for $A$ linear). It is certainly possible to prove under stricter assumptions (for example continuity of derivative viewed as a map $\mathbb{R}^n \to L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$), but I am looking for something given only the above and other conclusions (for example the uniqueness of $A$ if it exists) that can be made without assuming $A$ is linear. If it is impossible, please provide a reason or better yet some sort of specific counter-example.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It must be a linear function.  Otherwise, the linear approximation formula doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you must assume $A$ is linear. The value of $A(v)$ is the bi-directional derivative of $f$, at the point $x$, in the direction of $v$ and $-v$. Try the polar function
$$f(r, \theta) = r\sin(2\theta)$$
at the origin. The graph of this function consists of a union of lines passing through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so these bi-directional derivatives should exist in each direction. Given a vector $v = (r_0, \theta_0)$, then
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0 + tv) - f(0)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(tr_0, \theta_0)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{tr_0\sin(2\theta_0)}{t} = r_0\sin(2\theta_0).$$
If we define $A(r, \theta) = r\sin(2\theta)$, then the limit in the question holds. Moreover, uniqueness of limits implies that this is the only possible choice for $A$ so that the limit holds, but $A$ is not linear. For example, expressing $A$ as a function of cartesian coordinates to make addition easier,
\begin{align}
A(1,0) &= 1 \sin\left(2 \cdot 0\right) = 0 \\
A(0,1) &= 1 \sin\left(2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0 \\
A(1,1) &= \sqrt{2} \sin\left(2 \cdot \frac{\pi}{4}\right) = \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
Hope that helps!

Comment: Please correct me if I am mistaken, but since my definition of $A$ above requires that $A(-v) = - A(v)$ I don't think this is actually a legitimate counter-example; the limit above can't exist for at least one $v$ for the polyhedral function, so $A$, non-linear or not, cannot exist.

Comment: No, you're not mistaken, and I've edited the changes. Sorry about that.

Comment: Should $t(r_0, \theta_0)$ be $(t r_0, t \theta_0)$?

Comment: @Carcassi Not in this case. I'm using polar coordinates, so $r_0$ represents the length of the vector, and $\theta_0$ its direction. Scaling the vector corresponds to scaling the length only. That said, there is a bit of an error here. I considered the two-sided limit as $t \to 0$, and for $t < 0$, we have $t(r_0, \theta_0) = (|t|r_0, \theta_0 + \pi)$, since the direction is changed, and the radius cannot be negative.

Comment: Aren't you in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Shouldn't scalar multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^2$ multiplies all components? How can the vector space structure know what coordinates you are in? We are defining derivatives here, there is no notion of metric...

Comment: @Carcassi Yes, I am in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Continuity and differentiability mean the same thing. But, it’s a different coordinate system, i.e. another way of denoting the points in$\Bbb{R}$. Rather than $(r, \theta)$ referring to a distance of $r$ along the $x$-axis, and a distance of $\theta$ along the $y$-axis, it means, in this case, the vector, distance $r$ from the origin, that makes an angle of $\theta$ with the positive $x$-axis. The point I’m denoting by $(r,\theta)$ (which is in polar coordinates) would be $(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ in Cartesian coordinates.